# What effect used here? How can I reproduce it? (stutter, repeat, glitch)

Tags: processing, effect, glitch

In this track by Savant called "The Mind inside The Mind", there's a specific stutter/glitch effect used, it can be heard prominently between 4:04 and 4:11.

I can hear it's some kind of beat repeater, but I wonder what exact unit could have been used here and what settings.